# Sending mail using orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

I want to attach a PDF and send an email.

Following is my properties-local.xml files

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*" value="send"/>
    <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.email.*.*" value="true"/>

    <!-- Email configuration -->
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.host.*.*"   value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.from.*.*"   value="@gmail.com"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.to.*.*"   value="@gmail.com"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.username.*.*"    value="@gmail.com"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.credentials.*.*" value="123"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.encryption.*.*"  value="tls"/>
    <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.port.*.*"  value="587"/>
    <property  as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.email.subject"  value="Orbeon Form submission"/>

    <property  as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.email.body"  value="Orbeon Form submission"/>

    <property
      as="xs:string"
      name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.detail.buttons.send"
      value="Fancy Send"/>


     <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.email.attach-pdf.*.*" value="true"/>
     <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.email.attach-tiff.*.*"  value="false"/>
     <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.email.attach-xml.*.*"  value="true"/>

     <property
       as="xs:string"
       name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
       value='require-valid
             then pdf
             then email
             then send("http://www.google.com/")
             then navigate("/success")
             recover navigate("/failure")'/>

</properties>
```

But system always navigate to failure. I couldn't find any errors in orbeon.log files.

Are there any additional setting that I need to configure?

Comment: I would try to take it step by step. For example, try including only the `email` action in `oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*`.

Comment: Thank you for reply.If I remove calling pdf,it will work as expect.It send email with attached xml and pdf format document but it always navigate to failure link,

Comment: When I remove  send("http://www.google.com/") ,it works thank you very much your help

Comment: How can I add generated uuid to pdf  before calling email function

Comment: Which UUID is that? How do you want to generate it?

Comment: UUID is somewhat similar to document id of the form.I need to retrieve this id and display it in label

Comment: Where is it stored in the first place?

Comment: I could display document id like <xf:label><xf:output value="xxf:document-id()"/></xf:label> now I want to convert it into a Barcode Barcode 39 or barcode 128 and display it ,Is there any way to do it ,I configure  <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.pdf.barcode.*.*" value="true"/> in properties-local.xml but it won't work for me,I want to display barcode in orbeon page

Comment: The barcode only appears in the PDF. Are you saying you want to to appear in the browser, in the HTML page? If so that's currently not supported.